# Nested enumerate starting from 0

Tags: enumerate, nesting

Here is my latex code:

```
\begin{enumerate}
\item  
\begin{enumerate}
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

and here is the output

[image]

and here is what I want

[image]

As you see from the second picture, the number starts with 0 and it starts from the second row. How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}
\item  

\begin{enumerate}\setcounter{enumii}{-1}\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You also can define as `\settozero` the above command like:

```
\def\settozero{\setcounter{enumii}{-1}\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}}
```

and then you can use it just when the inner enumeration starts:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\settozero{\setcounter{enumii}{-1}\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  

\begin{enumerate}\settozero
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And somehow more automated:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\settozero{\setcounter{enumii}{-1}\renewcommand\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}}


\newenvironment{myenumerate}{\begin{enumerate}\ifx\c@enumii\undefined\relax\else\settozero\fi}{\end{enumerate}}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  

\begin{myenumerate}
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{myenumerate}

\item
\begin{myenumerate}
   \item Test 0
   \item Test 1
\end{myenumerate}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: They perfectly works on a new document, but I copied the code above and pasted to my document and it does not work the same way. The first raw has no number and others have a, b and c. Any idea why?

Comment: Try the last one and if it doesn't works just give me more information about your document. You may be redefine nested enumerations and have only "enumi" and "\c@enumi" without "enumii" ot "c@enumii"...

Comment: I see... I found what is your problem.... You use enumitem package... @StevenB.Segletes soplution is fine for your case. If you want you can just extend my automation if possible

Comment: Did you removed enumitem package?

Comment: Yes. After removing enumitem, it worked

Comment: Ok... If you/or someone else need enumitem the solution from @StevenB is the option for your/his case.

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item  
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*,itemindent=.5in,labelsep=.5in,start=0]
\item[]
\item  I do not feel sad. 
\item  I feel sad 
\item I am sad all the time and I can't snap out of it. 
\item I am so sad and unhappy that I can't stand it.
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `enumitem` provides the `start` option, so `start=0` is simpler.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thanks!  I will take that advice.